# Get median of array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, median

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I know you can get `min` and `max` by:

```
let min = arr.min()
let max = arr.max()
```

But how do you get the median?

Comment: what if your array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` ?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/median/52279

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get the `median` you can use the following:

```
let median = arr.sorted(by: <)[arr.count / 2]
```

In your case it will return `5`.

As @Nirav pointed out `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` will return `5` but should return `4.5`.

Use this instead:

```
func calculateMedian(array: [Int]) -> Float {
    let sorted = array.sorted()
    if sorted.count % 2 == 0 {
        return Float((sorted[(sorted.count / 2)] + sorted[(sorted.count / 2) - 1])) / 2
    } else {
        return Float(sorted[(sorted.count - 1) / 2])
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
let m2 = calculateMedian(array: array) // 4.5
```

Comment: Using `sorted` causes the algorithm to take O(*n* log *n*) time. If performance is important, opt for an [algorithm that completes in O(*n*) time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71705133/145173).

Answer (score 13):

The median is defined as the number in the middle of the sequence. If there is not one middle number, then it's the average of the two middle numbers.

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func median() -> Double {
        let sortedArray = sorted()
        if count % 2 != 0 {
            return Double(sortedArray[count / 2])
        } else {
            return Double(sortedArray[count / 2] + sortedArray[count / 2 - 1]) / 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that if the array is empty, the median is undefined. So a safe median function returns an optional, just like the `min()` and `max()` built-in methods do.

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
    func median() -> Double? {
        guard count > 0  else { return nil }

        let sortedArray = self.sorted()
        if count % 2 != 0 {
            return Double(sortedArray[count/2])
        } else {
            return Double(sortedArray[count/2] + sortedArray[count/2 - 1]) / 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

With that defined, you can write:

```
if let median = arr.median() {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone (like me) likes two*-liners:

```
let sorted = arr.sorted(by: <)
let median = Double(sorted[arr.count/2] + sorted.reversed()[arr.count/2])/2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithms that use `sorted` take *O*(*n* log *n*) time. That's typically not a problem for 9 numbers, but if your array is large, use an algorithm that completes in *O*(*n*) time. An example is this [k-th largest element algorithm](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Kth%20Largest%20Element). It recursively partitions the array, but doesn’t have to go through all the work to sort it, so it’s much faster.